# .append not replace similar elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of `div.slides` inside a `div.slider`. With js I get a `NodeList` of all `.slides` inside `.slider`: `let slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slider .slide');` perfectly fine (also the slider itself `const slider = document.querySelector('.slider');`).

But whenever I try to add a last element from `.slides` to front of the `.slider` - it removes the last `.slider`.

So, for example, from a list of `a b c` it should be `c a b c` but it becomes `c a b`.

I tried `slider.insertBefore(slides[slides.lenght -1, slides[0]);` `slider.appendChild(slides[slides.length - 1]);` and few other.

**How do I add a copy of a nodeList element to the start/end WITHOUT removing a similar/duplicant?**

*no jquery*

Comment: because the same element can not be in two locations at once. You need to clone it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Node.cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode):

```
slider.insertBefore(slides[slides.lenght -1].cloneNode(), slides[0]);
```

Both `insertBefore()` and `appendChild()` move the node to a new position without copying it.

From the [Node.insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) documentation:

> If the given node already exists in the document, `insertBefore()` moves
>   it from its current position to the new position. (That is, it will
>   automatically be removed from its existing parent before appending it
>   to the specified new parent.)
>
> This means that a **node cannot be in two locations of the document
>   simultaneously**.
>
> **Note**: The `Node.cloneNode()` can be used to make a copy of the node
>   before appending it under the new parent. Note that the copies made
>   with cloneNode() will not be automatically kept in sync.